# Stripe Webhooks. Dealing with multiple webhook events

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have a problem with Stripe Webhooks, especially with *payment_intent.processing* event.
In our old app which I have to maintain we're using 3 payment methods. One of them is SOFORT payment. The main difference of this payment method is that you should wait for the bank response a few days and then get Payment Succeeded response from the Stripe Webhook. But our application requires us to fill the client balance right at the moment when client paid. SOFORT is trustworthy and we never had cases when transaction been cancelled while it'd been processing.

But 2 days ago I faces a new problem when stripe created two *payment_intent.processing* events with 1 second interval and client got credits on his balance 2 times.
Here's a piece of code to explain what I mean:

```
$paymentIntent = $event->data->object;
$order = Db_Orders::getOrderPaymentIntentId($paymentIntent->id);
switch ($event->type) {
case 'payment_intent.processing':
    if ($order['wlo_payment_type'] == PAYMENT_METHOD_SOFORT && $order['wlo_status'] == W_LEADS_ORDER_STATUS_STARTED) Utils::activateOrderOffers($order['id']);
    $orderObj = new Db_LeadOrder();
    $orderObj->id = $order['id'];
    $orderObj->wlo_status = W_LEADS_ORDER_STATUS_PENDING;
    $orderObj->save();
    break;
case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
    if ($order['wlo_payment_type'] != PAYMENT_METHOD_SOFORT && $order['wlo_status'] != W_LEADS_ORDER_STATUS_SUCCESS) Utils::activateOrderOffers($order['id']);
    $orderObj = new Db_LeadOrder();
    $orderObj->id = $order['id'];
    $orderObj->wlo_response_date = Utils::formatDateDb(time());
    $orderObj->wlo_status = W_LEADS_ORDER_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    $orderObj->save();
    break;
  default:
    echo 'Received unknown event type ' . $event->type;
```

In *activateOrderOffers* function I do all the manipulation with client balance. And as you can see in *payment_intent.processing* event I execute it only for SOFORT payment method with STARTED (initial for all orders) status.

As I understand, in my case I'm listening for two parallel processing events. Am I right and are there any ideas how to solve that? I know, manipulating with balance while payment is not yet succeeded might be a bad practice, but that was the main requirement from the client.
Best regards to you all.

Comment: In my case I had the Stripe CLI still listening on events as well, that's why I received duplicates 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe webhook may resend events. According to best practices, you can consider logging events you already received.

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#duplicate-events

> Webhook endpoints might occasionally receive the same event more than once. We advise you to guard against duplicated event receipts by making your event processing idempotent. One way of doing this is logging the events you’ve processed, and then not processing already-logged events.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28493051)

Comment: Good catch, @NicoHaase! Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I am looking for.
Though Stripe support confirmed themselves that's it's quite strange, receiving multiple processing events.

Comment: No problem. It's worth to check out the Webhooks section in the dashboard to see how many times an event was sent.

Answer (score 2):

While it's unlikely, it is possible that multiple copies of the same event may be sent, so you need to [make your webhook handling code idempotent](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#duplicate-events) so as to handle that correctly.

Comment: What does that imply in concrete terms? Are the event IDs same for "same events"? The docs are very, very vague when it comes to actual details like this.